# Aframe resolution drops on mobile when exiting VR-mode

Tags: three.js, aframe, webvr

When switching back from VR-mode to 'normal' mode, the resolution of aframe scenes drop dramatically from about full HD to about 360p.

Not sure if this is at its core an Aframe, Three.js or general WebVR issue, but it seems to occur for every AFRAME application but not for other WebVR apps. The issue is encountered on the below mentioned android device, as well as at least one other android mobile and one iphone, but not on desktop browsers.

[Image when entered into VR mode: resolution is 1820x1080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeOPa.png)

[Image when exited VR mode: resolution changed to 640x360](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBzKV.png)

Note that the above resolutions were obtained using:
`AFRAME.scenes[0].renderer.getSize().width + "," + AFRAME.scenes[0].renderer.getSize().height + ", canvas: " + AFRAME.scenes[0].canvas.width + "," + AFRAME.scenes[0].canvas.height`

Though this issue happens consistently for me, I can't find any mentions on it online. Any suggestion (as well as  confirmation or rejection) is welcome!

Device info

`AFRAME: 0.8.2
Browsers: Firefox and Chrome for android
Phone: Huawei P10 lite 
Android: 7.0 (Nougat)`

Comment: I am having the same problem on my iPhone 6s (using Safari & Chrome) and Samsung s8 (using Chrome). I'm very curious if there is any solution to this problem.

Comment: I think i've found the solution to this problem: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3354#issuecomment-398749944

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my solution over here; https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3592 which seems similar to @Tostifrosti's solution in issue 3354 of the same repo (though that one doesn't involve changing code in the aframe library).

The solution was to add the following line afer [line 479 in a-scene.js](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/core/scene/a-scene.js#L479)

```
this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
```

Comment: While the content under that link may prove useful, it's better to paste here important and relevant parts of the solution, in case the target site is unreachable.